# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str on a Windows 10

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, nltk, frequency, word-frequency

I am trying to find out the inverse document frequency of a list of Sherlock Holmes stories. Have a look at the code:

Inverse document frequency is the measure of how common or rare a word is across multiple documents.

So, that would mean that Inverse Document Frequency or `idf` for short, measures how common a word is in a particular document which isn't quite as common in others.

The formula for idf is:
log x (Total_Documents/The_Number_Of_Documents_Containing(word))

**main.py**

```
import math
import nltk
import os
import sys


def main():

    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        sys.exit("Usage: python main.py corpus")
    print("Loading data...")
    corpus = load_data(sys.argv[1])

    words = set()
    for filename in corpus:
        words.update(corpus[filename])

    idfs = list()
    for word in words:
        f = sum(word in corpus[filename] for filename in corpus)
        idf = math.log(len(corpus) / f)
        idfs[word] = idf

    tfidfs = dict()
    for filename in corpus:
        tfidfs[filename] = []
        for word in corpus[filename]:
            tf = corpus[filename][word]
            tfidfs[filename].append((word, tf * idfs[word]))

    for filename in corpus:
        tfidfs[filename].sort(key=lambda tfidf: tfidf[1], reverse=True)
        tfidfs[filename] = tfidfs[filename][:5]

    print()
    for filename in corpus:
        print(filename)
        for term, score in tfidfs[filename]:
            print(f"    {term}: {score:.4f}")


def load_data(directory):
    files = dict()
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        with open(os.path.join(directory, filename)) as f:

            contents = [
                word.lower() for word in
                nltk.word_tokenize(f.read())
                if word.isalpha()
            ]

            frequencies = dict()
            for word in contents:
                if word not in frequencies:
                    frequencies[word] = 1
                else:
                    frequencies[word] += 1
            files[filename] = frequencies

    return files


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But when I run `python .\main.py .\shelock_holmes\` in Powershell,

I get this confusing error:

```
Loading data...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\main.py", line 65, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\main.py", line 22, in main
    idfs[word] = idf
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Actually, error message has enough information, I don't know what can be added.

Comment: Well, it's showing you a line of code that says `idfs[word] = idf`. This means that you have a list called `idfs`, and you want to use `word` as an index. The error message says that there is a TypeError, meaning, an error that has to do with something's type. Then it tells you that the thing you are trying to use as an index (i.e., `word`) is a string (`str`), and that instead an integer or a slice is required to index into a list. What exactly is confusing about this? Think carefully about what problem you want to solve with this line of code.

Comment: Hey! I'm a 12 year old, you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `idfs` as a list:

```
idfs = list()
```

If `udfs` is a list, then in this assignment:

```
idfs[word] = idf
```

`word` must be an integer, because it specifies an index or position within the list.

But it appears that `words` is a list of `str`, and so inside the iteration:

```
for word in words:
```

`word` is a `str`.  Since a `str` is not an integer, the line

```
idfs[word] = idf
```

causes the error you're getting, for exactly the reason that it explains. Maybe `idfs` should be a `dict` rather than a list, defined like this:

```
idfs = dict()
```

Then the line:

```
idfs[word] = idf
```

interprets `word` as a key in the dictionary, and assigns `idf` as the value of that key in the `dict`.  Dictionary keys can be any object, and are most often strings, so this makes good sense.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `idfs` is a list. And `idfs[word] = idf` adds key-values to it like a dictionary. So you should instead of `idfs = list()` make it `idfs = {}` a dictionary. Otherwise if you need list, then use `.append()` to add items to the end.